# Prevent Enter key from constantly incrementing counter

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS app that increments a counter if the user has guessed a sound. The incrementation works but if the user holds the enter key the score keeps going up until he releases the key, how can I avoid that so that he just scores one point and if he tries to hit enter again on the same sound the counter stops adding one point?

I tried adding a `boolean` value, but it doesn't work, here is my JavaScript:

```
var sounds = [
  {
    animalType: 'horse',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Horse-neigh.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'bear',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/grizzlybear.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'goat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Goat-noise.mp3'),
  },
  {
    animalType: 'cat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/cat.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'dog',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/dog-bark.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'sheep',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/sheep.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'rooster',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/rooster.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'lion',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/lion.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'hen',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/hen.mp3')
  }
]

var player = document.getElementById('player');
var enteredWord = document.getElementById('entered-word');
var counter = document.getElementById('counter-score');
var errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
var wrongAnswerSound = new Audio('../sounds/Wrong-answer-sound-effect.mp3');
var isEntered = false;

function startGame() {
    var currentSound;
    player.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
    currentSound = sound.animalType;
    sound['sound'].play();
  })


  enteredWord.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
      if(enteredWord.value.toLowerCase() === currentSound && !isEntered) {
        counter.textContent ++;
        isEntered = true;
        errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
        enteredWord.classList.remove('input-error-border');
        console.log(soundPlayedCount)
      } else {
        errorMessage.style.display = 'inline-block';
        enteredWord.classList.add('input-error-border');
        wrongAnswerSound.play();
      }  
      isEntered = false;
    } 
  })
}

startGame();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have misplaced the following assignment:

```
isEntered = false;
```

It should be within the `else` block. Where you have it now, it will make `isEntered` always `false` even when you had just set it to `true`. ;)

I would also advise to listen to the `input` event (instead of `keydown`), as the `input` event will also trigger when input changes are made via a mouse drag/drop, or via the context menu (e.g. paste), or via other input devices.

Comment: I placed the boolean assignment in the else block it prevents the user from constantly incrementing the score when pressing the enter, but once the user has made one successful guess he cannot continue to update his score if he guesses again

Comment: I am not sure how you intend it to work. After a correct guess, should not the player button be clicked? Or how else will a new sound be selected? In that click handler you should probably clear the input and set `isEntered = false;`. Anyway, this seems to be another question. I suggest you first try yourself, and when you can't make that to work, ask a new question about that specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to use `keyup` rather than `keydown`, that way the score will increase each time he releases the key. As the problem right now is when he keeps on pressing the key, the `keydown` listener keeps on getting executed.

```
enteredWord.addEventListener('keyup', function() {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this: 
Listen for `change` instead of `keydown`.
When it fires, add the `disabled` attribute to the input.
When you're ready to accept input again, remove the `disabled` attribute.

Note that

> "The difference [between `oninput` and `onchange`] is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the
>   value of an element has changed [eg after each keypress], while onchange occurs when the
>   element loses focus, after the content has been changed. The other
>   difference is that the onchange event also works on  elements."